# image transforms issue with CMYK images

Tags: image-transforms, image

The builtin craft image resizer tool appears to be having issues with CMYK source images, we're using Craft 2.5 (latest version)

Original source image

http://2b45fe03c2dbd491035c-f318885d2d6632cd7d9eb38c0fa500f2.r62.cf1.rackcdn.com/new_site/film/images/EXM_D016_02432_42886.jpg

Transforms to this

http://2b45fe03c2dbd491035c-f318885d2d6632cd7d9eb38c0fa500f2.r62.cf1.rackcdn.com/new_site/film/images/_assetImageGrid/EXM_D016_02432_42886.jpg

Is there a solution to this issue that we can implement, or is it simply a case that CMYK images cannot be resized by the system?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using GD or Imagick? You can check which one is installed by going to yourdomain.com/admin/utils/phpinfo

Comment: It looks like Imagmagik
https://www.dropbox.com/s/extqsgvm8ouddw5/Screenshot%202016-02-26%2017.54.18.jpg?dl=0
But I can see the GD library is also available
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yyfn8z3geuju0m/Screenshot%202016-02-26%2017.54.34.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Hrm... any chance you could update the Imagick library  (https://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php) as well as the PHP wrapper (https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=imagick)?  Trying to rule out if it's an Imagick bug or not.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a shared hosting platform I'm not able to make any changes to the php modules.  If it helps, this is a new issue, since we moved from craft 2.x to 2.5.x as transforms didn't used to have any issue with CYMK (it's the same source images files) so it's since I upgraded and cleared the image cache so the transforms were re-created that the issue has occurred.  Update to latest craft occurred in the last couple of days.

Comment: Can you share the image transform code/settings you're using?

Comment: HI Brad, sure, these are the settings I have set, https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngmfh4ld5ly93up/Screenshot%202016-02-26%2023.10.52.jpg?dl=0, let me know if you need more information from somewhere.

Comment: Hi Dave - Could you give us more info about what "issues" actually means? Are the images being generated, but not displayed? If the images are the only part of the page which aren't loading, then could you attempt to increase your memory allowance? Are you seeing a 'stuck' process "Generating pending image transforms" in Craft?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific the "issue" is that this source image 
http://2b45fe03c2dbd491035c-f318885d2d6632cd7d9eb38c0fa500f2.r62.cf1.rackcdn.com/new_site/film/images/EXM_D016_02432_42886.jpg
When compared to the transformed image
http://2b45fe03c2dbd491035c-f318885d2d6632cd7d9eb38c0fa500f2.r62.cf1.rackcdn.com/new_site/film/images/_assetImageGrid/EXM_D016_02432_42886.jpg
The colours are all incorrect, the transformed image is very dark, overall the transform has not complete as expected, where the image colours have been (reasonably) translated from CYMK to RGB

Answer (score 1):

Craft Developer has responded and confirmed that there was an issue and offered a fix, this issue will be resolved in the next release of Craft.  Version 2.5.2767 contains the issue, so any version higher than this will contain the fix.